# How to sync SVN and Git repositories?

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control

My client is using SVN and my company is using Git (central bare Git repo). So I have the task to sync both servers. I can't use SubGit , because I can't do any modification on either server.

I successfully used git-svn to download the SVN to my local Git repo (using TortoiseGit). But I can't figure out how to set up a remote upstream to the central Git Repository (using Egit in Eclipse).

Is it possible to set up a remote branch, so I can check in the SVN stuff from my local Git into the central Git repo? How?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can't update hooks in SVN and Git repositories. That complicates the task a lot, because you can't reject pushes Git if someone is committing to SVN at the same moment and vice versa.

I think, that git-svn is not a solution because on sending commits to SVN ("git svn dcommit") it changes Git commit SHA-1 to add `git-svn-id:` signature. As result when one pushes commit C to your Git repository, you fetch that commit to your git-svn repsository, run "git svn dcommit", it translates it to SVN and adds `git-svn-id:` signature to commit message thus changing commit SHA-1, so you'll get another commit C' in git-svn repository. After that C' should be sent back to the Git repository, and after that the user that pushed C should download C' and replace C with C' in his working copy. So you won't have easy and transparent synchronization.

With SubGit you can reduce your problem to synchronization of 2 Git repositories by creation of an "intermediate" Git repository with SubGit installed into it. Synchronization of 2 Git repositories is a simpler task (and there's a lot of solutions on the internet) but it's still isn't a piece of cake, because 2 different users can push into both repositories simultaneously (and you can't discard one of the push, because you can't create hooks in the repositories). If these changes are conflicting, you can resolve that **only manually**, and I'm afraid this is the best you can do: create a repository with 2 remote and using a script constantly fetch changes from one of them and push the changes to another one and vice versa (and notify the administrator and stop synchronization on simultaneous conflicting changes).

Disclaimer: I can be biased because I'm one of SubGit developers.